# git: merge file that has been reordered

Tags: git

I have a branch in which I've been doing some surgery on a single (Python) file, while development continues on the same file in the main branch. Normally this is easily dealt with by `git merge`, but one of the bigger changes I've made was to reorder the classes inside the file. As a result, git's merge algorithm is getting hopelessly confused. Is there a way to tell it to merge a particular part of the file from one side, with a different part on the other side?

Comment: I have thought this problem before, sounds no such functionality in git :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the patience strategy (`-s patience`) might help *a little*, because it matches on the unique lines in the file instead of repeated lines.  The other option that comes to mind is to do an interactive rebase (`-i`) instead of a merge, which lets you go patch by patch if you like.  There isn't an interactive option for `merge`.  Other than that, it's just one of those situations where you have to bite the bullet and do it the hard way.  Using a graphical merge tool can make it a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up getting a different from the main branch and applying bits manually by cut and paste :(

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an entire file to overwrite the other with [`git merge -s ours branch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html), but I'm not aware of a way to split a file.